# Quarkus Flyway add new Database Type

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, quarkus, flyway

How can I add an new Database Type in flyway?

I tried to create a new maven plugin project which have java driver classes, with the same structor as into the flyway package.

But it will not load my plugin at startup at flyway in quarkus.

Comment: Suggest you improve the clarity of your question. Are you trying to get Flyway to work with  Db2-for-i  (i-series / as400) because if you are then it is currently not a supported database in Flyway, AFAIK).  Your question lacks precision, needs to show versions, operating-system details, exact configs and exact error messages etc.  Improve your question by editing it, or risk it getting closed for lack of detail.

Comment: Yes I try to create an database adapter for  Db2-for-i (i-series / as400) plugin. At the startup of flyway it will load all classes which will implement the interface "Plugin". But it will not load the implentation of my "Plugin" class at startup.

Comment: you dont need to write a plugin check https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#other-databases

Comment: Thats true, but for flyway it will not work!